# VueJS decrypting values using CyptoJS gives error "Decryption failed TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, encryption

I have a Laravel backend that uses `Crypt::encrypString` to encrypt data before saving it in the database like:

```
$message = new WA_Message;
$message->content = Crypt::encryptString($received_message);
$message->is_business_message = false;
$message->conversation_id = $conversation->id;
$message->save();
```

When I call it in the frontend and want to decrypt it to render it it gives me the following error:

```
Decryption failed TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Object.xorBlock (crypto-js.js?v=3aa22fc9:2402:41)
```

As the key I copied the Laravel appkey after `base64:` and put it in the .env of the Vuejs app to test.

Vuejs

```
decryptedMessage() {
    try {
        const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(this.message.content, CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(import.meta.env.VITE_LARAVEL_APP_KEY));
        const stringDecrypted = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        return stringDecrypted;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Decryption failed', error);
        return '';
    }
},
```

The text that was encrypted: `bzbz` .

The ciphertext: `eyJpdiI6Im94UU5zZ1hLQk5ySkw5Z21lZnExYVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiK1RTOFNEeXY5Q0U0Slh2ZmpUUEMrZz09IiwibWFjIjoiYTM1NzVkNjg2MDliZDI0MDUwNDljMzM5OTlhNDNjNWVkMTI1NmIwNTA4YTI2YzA2NWU4MmZjYzgzMjAxMGYyMCIsInRhZyI6IiJ9`

The key: `base64:G3EfLG42xzqWAH1PuoZ72mUTJ1bC8EJMzx+1jqa7/m0=`

Comment: Post complete (non-productive) test data: Plaintext and key used for encryption in the Laravel backend, and resulting ciphertext.

Comment: @Topaco like this?

Answer (score 0):

The following can be deduced from the [Laravel code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php) and confirmed with your test data:

The ciphertext is encrypted with AES in CBC mode with PKCS#7 padding. For authentication, an HMAC/SHA256 is generated from the concatenation of IV and ciphertext with the encryption key.
The encryption data is stored as JSON with the properties `value` (actual ciphertext), `iv` (IV), `mac` (HMAC/SHA256) and `tag` (AEAD tag, only relevant for AEAD ciphers such as GCM, not used here).

For decryption, the ciphertext, IV and HMAC/SHA256 must first be determined from the JSON, then the authentication is performed and, if authentication is successful, the actual decryption. A possible implementation with CryptoJS is:

```js
var keyWA = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('G3EfLG42xzqWAH1PuoZ72mUTJ1bC8EJMzx+1jqa7/m0=')
var ciphertextB64 = 'eyJpdiI6Im94UU5zZ1hLQk5ySkw5Z21lZnExYVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiK1RTOFNEeXY5Q0U0Slh2ZmpUUEMrZz09IiwibWFjIjoiYTM1NzVkNjg2MDliZDI0MDUwNDljMzM5OTlhNDNjNWVkMTI1NmIwNTA4YTI2YzA2NWU4MmZjYzgzMjAxMGYyMCIsInRhZyI6IiJ9'

// Get JSON with encryption data (cihertext, iv, mac)
var ciphertextWA = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertextB64)
var ciphertextJsonStr = ciphertextWA.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
var ciphertextJson = JSON.parse(ciphertextJsonStr)
console.log("JSON:", ciphertextJson)

// authenticate IV and ciphertext
var ivValueWA = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(ciphertextJson.iv + ciphertextJson.value);
var hmacIvValueWA = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(ivValueWA, keyWA);
if (ciphertextJson.mac === hmacIvValueWA.toString()){
  
    // authentication succeeded: decrypt data
    var ivWA = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertextJson.iv);
    var decryptedDataWA = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertextJson.value, keyWA, {iv: ivWA})
    console.log("Decrypted data:", decryptedDataWA.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))
} else {
  
    // authentication failed: data integrity compromised, therefore no decryption
    console.log('decryption failed...')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.2.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

The code successfully decrypts the ciphertext you posted with the corresponding key.

---

Note that CryptoJS has been [discontinued](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js?tab=readme-ov-file#discontinued). The latest version is 4.2.0.